# Error al registrar usuario PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Tengo un problema al intetnar registrar usuarios al php con mysql, el codigo es este:

```
$server = 'server';

$bd = 'basedata';

$user = 'usuario';

$pass = 'password';

$conexion = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$bd);

if (mysqli_errno()){

        die('<p>Error al conectar con el servidor MySQL');
    }else{
        echo "conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (id, usuario, pass) VALUES ('dummy', '".$user."','".$pass."');";
        if($conexion->query($sql)){
            echo "Exito al registrar";
        }else{
            echo "Error al hacer sql<br>";
            var_dump($sql);
        }
    }
```

Se conecta a la base de datos, pero el error es al registrar al usuario, no quiere hacer el INSERT INTO del sql, los nombres de las entidades y tablas..

VAR_DUMP:

```
conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!
Error al hacer sql

string(99) "INSERT INTO Usuarios (id, usuario, pass) VALUES ('dummy', 'as','f970e2767d0cfe75876ea857f92e319b');"
```

Gracias.

Comment: el 

`if($conexion->query($sql)){
            echo "Exito al registrar";
        }`
No funciona, asi que pasa al else, el problema esta aqí.

Comment: estas enviando un 'dummy' en el id que imagino debe ser null o int, a proposito puedes hacer `var_dump (mysql_error());`

Comment: El id es  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, no se cúal es el conficto..

Lo del 'dummy' es por poner algo, ya que luego como solo es int te lo pone en numero y va sumando +1

Comment: esta entre comillas quita el dummy y coloca null y te debe funcionar

Comment: No funciona poniendo null, sigue igual

Comment: Has añadido un `;` de más en tu sentencia, fíjate bien al final `$pass."');";`. Podrías eliminar el `id` de tu `insert` ya que este es incrementado automático, algo así `"INSERT INTO Usuarios (usuario, pass) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."')";`

Comment: el `;` está bien, es el cierre de la sentencia sql que se tiene que poner al final

Comment: Lo he probado y nada

Comment: actualmente lo tengo asi `if(isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])){
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  $pass = md5($pass);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (id, usuario, pass) VALUES ('null', '".$user."','".$pass."');";
  if($conexion->query($sql)){
   echo "Exito al registrar";
  }else{
   echo "Error<br>";
   var_dump($sql);
  }`

Comment: Pero nada, sigue tirando error

Comment: La respuesta de abajo se ha acercado, ya que he conseguido que ejecute la version del try and catch y me daba 'Inserto correctamente'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa try y catch para conocer el error.

try{
  $conexion->query($sql);
  echo 'Inserto correctamente';
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}

Comment: Al hacer el try and catch , ha salido esto como resultado:

`
conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!Inserto correctamente
`

Comment: la query funciona, creo

Comment: Al copiar la sentencia MYSQL y meterla manualmente desde el panel de comando sql cambiando las variables $user y $pass por cualquier cosa, funciona.

Comment: El problema tiene que estar aqui `if($conexion->query($sql)){
   echo "Exito al registrar";
  }else{
   echo "Error<br>";
   var_dump($sql);
  }`

Comment: Primero comprueba que la conexion es exitosa: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  Despues ejecuta tu query $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

Comment: Este es el resultado al ejecutar tu codigo: `conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!Error: INSERT INTO Usuarios (id, usuario, pass) VALUES ('null', 'Julian','b48fa8c675292d2cef0518810dc0a70f');`

Comment: Para comenzar, en ningún lado del código se imprime ese mensaje 'conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!'. Como consejo te recomiendo primero entender la logica del lo que pretendes hacer y despues considerar los tips que se comparten en estos posts. Te dejo un link que te puede servir. Suerte! https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

¿Te aparece algún error en pantalla o algo para que pueda hacerme a la idea de lo que está pasando? De todas formas, puedes probar a hacer la consulta con PHP "normal" (no orientado a objetos).

Para ello, sustituye

```php
if($conexion->query($sql)){
```

por

```php
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die ('Error al realizar la consulta');
//Compruebo que el registro se haya guardado correctamente
$sql="SELECT id FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die ('Error al realizar la consulta');
if($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
```

Quizás así te funcione, prueba por si acaso.

Por cierto, revisando tu código, te recomiendo que compruebes antes de guardar el usuario en la base de datos si ya existe algún usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario, no sé si tenías pensado hacerlo más adelante.

Espero que te sea de ayuda. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Lo de comprobar que el usuario no este cogido ya lo he pensado, pero para este proyecto no hace falta ya que solo habran 2 usuarios.

Comment: Al hacerlo me sale `Error al realizar la consulta`

Comment: @Juliian68 Vale, pues entonces comprueba las siguientes cosas: A. Asegúrate de que los parámetros de conexión estén bien, tiene que ser algo parecido a esto: mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "password"). También puedes hacerlo con variables ($servidor, $usuario, $password), pero asegúrate de poner el texto entre comillas al definir la variable. B. Sustituye or die("Error al realizar la consulta") por or die($sql), copia el código que te aparezca y ejecútalo directamente en el gestor de la base de datos (supongo que será mysql). Mira a ver si así te da error o no.

Comment: @Juliian68 También puedes seleccionar la base de datos con el siguiente código: $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Error al seleccionar la base de datos" );
Por cierto, si solo son 2 usuarios también puedes insertarlos manualmente en el gestor de bases de datos que tengas (supongo que será mysql)

Comment: Pero la conexion con la base de datos creo que es correcta, porque tengo esto `$conexion = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$bd);
 if (mysqli_errno()){
  die('<p>Error al conectar con el servidor MySQL');
 }else{
  echo "conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!";
 }
`

Comment: Y cuando intento registrar la conexion con la base sale que ``conectad@ correctamente a la base de datos!

Comment: por cierto, metiendo los datos desde mysql funciona perfectamente copiando mi sentencia sql

Comment: No insertes nada en el campo id, si está configurado como autoincrementable se completa solo, quizás al insertar un valor, aunque sea nulo, da error. Es decir, $sql = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (usuario, pass) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."')"; Y asegúrate de que la tabla se llame Usuarios con mayúsculas y el nombre de las columnas esté todo en minúsculas (tal y como lo has puesto en el código PHP), que por tontería que parezca a mí una vez me pasó.